# Autenticacion de usuario no funciona correctamente

Tags: php, angular, autenticacion

Estoy preparando un proyecto para desarrollo web, estoy en la parte de verificar el inicio de sesion del usuario para darle un jwtToken y asi mantenerlo con sesion iniciada mientras sigue navegando el sitio, ahora mismo mi base de datos esta vacia, por lo que al poner cualquier email y contraseña, deberia dar el mensaje de error que tengo preparado en mi html, pero pareciera que nunca se activa correctamente la autenticacion, por que al dar enter me deja entrar al inicio de la pagina, que me esta faltando hacer? Comparto abajo el HTML del componente de inicio de sesion, su archivo .ts, mi servicio de autenticacion, mi guard y el archivo auth.php en el que valido los datos y envio el token

```js
export class AutenticacionService {
  private jwtHelper: JwtHelperService = new JwtHelperService();
  private refreshTimeout: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login (email: string, clave: string): Observable<any> {
    let retorno = new Observable(loginApi => {
      let credenciales = { email : email, clave : clave };
      this.http.post(environment.baseUrl + 'login', credenciales)
        .subscribe({
          next      : (response: any) => {
            localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', response.jwt);
            loginApi.next(response.jwt);
          },
          error     : (err) => { loginApi.error(err); },
          complete  : () => { loginApi.complete(); }
        });
    });
    return retorno;
  }

  isLogged(){
    let token: string | null = localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');
    return token && !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
  }

  logout(){
    localStorage.removeItem('jwtToken');
  }

  refreshLogin(){
    let obs = this.http.post(environment.baseUrl + 'refresh', {});
    obs.subscribe({
      next      : (response: any) => {
        localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', response.jwt);
      },
      error     : (err) => {
        console.error(err);
        this.logout();
      },
      complete  : () => {
        this.programarRefresh();
      }
    });
  }

  programarRefresh (): void {
    let tiempoParaRefresh = this.calcularExpira() - 60000;
    this.refreshTimeout = setTimeout(()=>{
      this.refreshLogin();
    }, tiempoParaRefresh);
  }

  private calcularExpira (): number {
    let jwtToken = localStorage.getItem('jwtToken') || '';
    let timeout = this.jwtHelper.getTokenExpirationDate(jwtToken) || new Date();
    return (timeout.getTime() - Date.now());
  }
}
```

```js
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  public jwtHelper: JwtHelperService = new JwtHelperService();
  constructor(private router: Router) {}
 
  canActivate(): boolean {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
    if (token && !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)) {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(["login"]);
    return false;
  }
 }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="back-arrow">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-left" routerLink=""></i>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid vh-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center m-0 p-0">
        <div class="text-center">
          <h1>ScoutLink</h1>
          <form #loginForm="ngForm">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="InputEmail">EMAIL</label>
                <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="credenciales.email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" placeholder="Ingresa tu email" [disabled]="autenticando">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="InputPassword">CONTRASEÑA</label>
                <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="credenciales.pass" class="form-control" id="InputPassword" placeholder="Contraseña" [disabled]="autenticando">
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="errorLogin" class="alert alert-danger">Email o contraseña incorrectos.</div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg px-5 py-3 me-sm-3 fs-6 fw-bolder" routerLink="/inicio" (click)="login()" [disabled]="autenticando">Iniciar sesion</button>
                </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

CODIGO PHP:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

function autenticarUsuario($email, $clave) {
    $db = conectarBD();
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $email);
    $clave = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $clave);
    $sql = "SELECT usuarios.id, usuarios.email, usuarios.contrasena FROM usuarios WHERE usuarios.email = $email AND usuarios.contrasena = $clave";
    $result = mysqli_query ($db, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
        $token = generarTokenJWT($email);
        return $token;
    }
    return null;
}

function generarTokenJWT($email) {
    $clave_jwt = 'finalWeb';
    $tiempo_expiracion = time() + (60 * 60);

$payload = array(
    "email" => $email,
    "exp" => $tiempo_expiracion
);

$token = JWT::encode($payload, $clave_jwt);
return $token;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
    $email = $data['email'];
    $clave = $data['clave'];

$token = autenticarUsuario($email, $clave);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('jwt' => $token));
}

?>
```

Comment: y el error cual es?

Comment: Que al intentar ingresar con un usuario inexistente no salta el error al usuario, lo deja ingresar como si las credenciales fueran correctas cuando no lo son

Comment: mmm entiendo y pusiste el codigo que hace esa validacion??? puedes hacer un dump de los datos que recibe y que retorna?